# Elementary Length of a contour

Tags: complex-analysis

> Parametrize the contour consisting of the perimeter of the square with
>   vertices $-1-i,1-i,1+i,$ and $-1+i$ traversed once in that order. What
>   is the length of this contour?

I have already parameterized it but I am having difficulty finding the length. 
I know that the arc length for complex numbers is: $$l(\lambda) = \int_a^b|\frac{ds}{dt}|dt = \int_a^b|\frac{dz}{dt}|dt$$, where $l(\lambda)$ = length of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

its just a square where all 4 sides have length 2, so the length is +/- 8 depending on clockwise/counterclockwise.

Answer (score 1):

One possible parametrization is 
$$\lambda(t)=\begin{cases}-1-i+t&\text{if }0\le t\le 2,\\1-i+i(t-2)&\text{if }2\le t\le 4, \\
1+i-2(t-4)&\text{if }4\le t\le 6,\\-1+i-2i(t-6)&\text{if }6\le t\le 8.\end{cases}$$
What do you get for absolute value of the derivative and hece for the integral then?

Comment: For the parametrization I got the same thing except I parameterizd it $0\leq t \leq 1$.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. (check that)

Comment: When you asked what i got "for absolute value of the derivative and hence for the integral" that is what i am having trouble with constructing. How can i construct it?

Comment: When I construct it do I only worry about the t in in this case since the constants will be 0 if I take the derivative?